# VPN router only accessible with new default routes instead of standard gateway setting

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, iptables

On my Ubuntu machines I configured a router for internal VPN Access as VM.

The VM is only used to have masked connections going out to the internet. No connections are made from outside to lan or so. The basis is this: https://mschoofs.blogspot.com/2020/08/vpn-gateway-vm-in-virtualbox.html. Its a simple iptables config with a start script for vpn.

(For testing purposes I set all given iptable rules to ACCEPT instead of DROP, so this cannot be the problem)

I wonder why I can't access it by simply setting it as the default gateway on other machines via GUI on a DHCP or fixed IP-Setting.

I can only access the VPN by setting a new default route on the other machines like e. g.
`route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.178.111`. This is not very comfortable since every device needs to change default routes.

When I configure other machines with a dhcp or a fixed ip and gateway 192.168.178.111 it only produces timeouts. Why? What am I doing wrong? Or how can I use the VPN router easily as standard for outgoing connections without further config over the normal gui setting on the clients (Win, Mac, Linux)?

Thank you!

Comment: What "actual" configuration do both methods produce? That is, if you list the resulting routing table in both cases (`ip -4 route`), what are the differences?

Comment: The weird thing is: They produce exactly the same output although the direct gateway setting (gnome gui, but also mac, win guis)  is NOT working, but the setting via default route (netplan, also manually default route on mac) is. 
"default via 192.168.178.111 dev enp5s0 proto static metric 100"

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I forgot to set DNS, now working!